# When will the effect function for angular signals execute?

Tags: angular, signals, angular-signals

Why do these two functions #workingUpdate and #brokenUpdate behave differently?
I actually would expect both functions to fail since the ElementRef does not exist while the constructor is called.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'test-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
  <button (click)="addOne()">count+</button><br/>
  count: {{count()}}<br/>
  output1: <span #output1></span><br/>
  output2: <span #output2></span><br/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  count = signal(0);

  @ViewChild('output1') output1!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('output2') output2!: ElementRef;

  #workingUpdate = () => {
    const c = this.count();
    this.output1.nativeElement.innerHTML = c;
  };
  #brokenUpdate = () => {
    this.output2.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.count();
  };

  constructor() {
    effect(this.#workingUpdate);
    effect(this.#brokenUpdate);
  }

  addOne() {
    this.count.update((c) => c + 1);
  }
}
```

I created a simple [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-q8pm8j?file=src%2Fmain.ts).
I originaly ran into this problem calling a update interface of a third party component.
I use the #workingUpdate stucture to fix my problem, but now im not sure if i've just hidden the actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the specific question, from the docs:

> An effect is an operation that runs whenever one or more signal values change.

> Effects always run at least once. When an effect runs, it tracks any
> signal value reads. Whenever any of these signal values change, the
> effect runs again. Similar to computed signals, effects keep track of
> their dependencies dynamically, and only track signals which were read
> in the most recent execution.
>
> Effects always execute asynchronously, during the change detection
> process.

Your example is very interesting.

It *does* work if I add `console.log()` and read the signal there.

```
  #workingUpdate = () => {
    console.log('working', this.count());
    const c = this.count();
    this.output1.nativeElement.innerHTML = c;
  };
  #brokenUpdate = () => {
    console.log('broken', this.count());
    this.output2.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.count();
  };
```

Almost looks like it isn't correctly registering the signal for the effect in the `#brokenUpdate` case?

UPDATE:
I got an answer on this from the Angular team.

Basically, the `brokenUpdate` case doesn't ever register the signal since it throws an exception the first time. So it is never getting re-run when the signal changes.

The `workingUpdate` case registers the signal before throwing the error. So it is re-run when the signal changes.

One way to fix it is to make the element refs static so they are there when the effects run. Something like this:

```
  @ViewChild('output1', { static: true }) output1!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('output2', { static: true }) output2!: ElementRef;
```

Comment: I updated the answer to include information I received from the Angular team.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I don't think the behaviour is very intuitive, because in the end both functions should invoke the same error of output(1|2) not being defined. But that might be just a "me problem" :).

Comment: If you comment out the `brokenUpdate` effect and just run the `workingUpdate`, you'll see that it *does* generate an error the first time. But unlike an Observable, an effect will re-execute after an error if its signal is registered before the error occurs. So the `workingUpdate` generates the error the first time. Then when you click the count button the signal is changed and the effect runs again. But by then the `output2` is defined and it works from that point on.

Comment: Ah okay, i think i understand it now. Thank you again. 
I need to dive a bit deeper into signals and error handling.